# how to display detail bound one time per group in iReport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have created a report in IReport with 3 groups(date,id,category). In the details bound i put items which belong to the category.
it means every category has the same items(the quantity of items are dynamic).the items shows up under every category what i do not want.

I want to display my detail one time for the category goup. it means for high, low and medium category the details should show up just one time. as in picture detail shows up 3 times it is not what i want.

**Does any one know how to do it in ireport?**

[image]

Comment: can you post your JRXML?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the "Print When Expression" property for your detail band: $V{REPORT_COUNT} == 1

Edited to add: try $V{COLUMN_COUNT} == 1. Maybe REPORT_COUNT wasn't working for you because of your groups.

Comment: Error: Incompatible operand type Integer and int

Comment: error is fixed with: new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}== new Integer("1") ) but nothing shows up in detail bound